# Specific kind of color picker

Tags: color

I'm looking for an HSL color picker with the following:

1. It has a color wheel with the Hue and the Saturation
2. It has a slider with lightness/brightness

Does such a color picker exist? I really just want these simple criteria, no pre-generated color schemes that users can toggle between or anything of that variety

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search leads to [this](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/color/hsl-picker.html).

[image: HSL Color Picker]

Comment: This literally is nothing at all like what I asked for.

Comment: I asked for very specific criteria.

One slider (for lightness)
And a color wheel to adjust hue and saturation, I'd also prefer to keep the naming conventions I listed: hue and saturation, not luminance.